How do I install Python dev-dependencies using uv?
I'm trying out uv to manage my Python project's dependencies and virtualenv but I can't see how to install all my dependencies for local development, including the dev dependencies.
In my pyproject.toml I have this kind of thing:
[project]
name = "my-project"
dependencies = [
  "django",
]

[tool.uv]
dev-dependencies = [
  "factory-boy",
]

[tool.uv.pip]
python-version = "3.10"

I can do the following to create a virtualenv and then generate a requirements.txt lockfile, which does not contain dev-dependencies (which is OK, because that is for production):
$ uv venv --python 3.10
$ uv pip compile pyproject.toml -o requirements.txt

But I can't see how to install all the dependencies in my virtualenv.
uv pip sync will use the requirements.txt.
There's also uv sync but I don't understand how that differs, and trying that generates an error:
error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['conf', 'hines', 'docker', 'assets', 'node_modules'].


I've noticed there's an open issue to be able to export dev dependencies to a file, which (I assume) means you could create both requirements-dev.txt and requirements.txt files.

EDIT: See the more recent answer by Cas.
One solution is to change the dev dependencies' in pyproject.toml from this:
[tool.uv]
dev-dependencies = [
  "factory-boy",
]

To this:
[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
  "factory-boy",
]

Then you can install all the dependencies in the virtualenv using
:
$ uv pip install -r pyproject.toml --extra dev

I don't know if this is the best solution at the moment, or if there will be a better one in the future as uv is developed.

This has become easier since uv v0.4.0.
With a pyproject.toml like:
[project]
name = "my-project"
dependencies = [
  "django",
]
requires-python = "~=3.10"
version = "1.0"

[tool.uv]
dev-dependencies = [
  "factory-boy",
]

Then doing:
$ uv venv --python 3.10
$ uv sync

Creates the virtual environment with the chosen Python version, and installs all the dependencies, including the dev ones.
Note that specifying the python version in both the pyproject.toml and with the uv venv command seems to be the only way to get that to work without any warning messages.

Thanks for the answer, if you want to uv sync another extra other than "dev", you can do uv sync --extra <my_extra_name>

To me it seems like we're no longer supposed to use uv pip install directly, but rather use uv run and/or uv sync, and by looking at uv sync --help it seems like it does install dev deps by default.
So workflow now seems to be

uv init for new projects
uv add/remove to manage deps, add --dev if it's a test dep
uv sync to ensure deps are up-to-date -- note: tool.uv dev deps are installed by default, those you add with uv add --dev
Other extras go still under std metadata, like optional, extraneous deps which are useful when running the system but not necessary

uv might be a still fast moving target, but this seems to work well for me.
Edit: I suppose main difference between uv sync and uv pip install is that you should prefer former if you want to use exact, locked set of dependencies (stored in uv.lock, hence also name sync) and uv pip install if you don't want to deal with locked deps, but not sure about this

Yes it seems to have got a bit easier recently. I'm not clear on when would should use uv pip ... commands now, other than for generating a requirements.txt where necessary. BTW, I'm not sure if you finished your answer – it ends suddenly and a couple of bullet points are duplicated?

Thanks! admittedly wrote that in a hurry, didn't notice it wasn't complete.
For some reason I can't now find the place in docs where they suggested not to use uv pip install but just uv add & uv sync

To expand on the other good answers by Phil
Dependency Groups
With uv >= 0.4.27 we can use the new Python packaging feature dependency groups to make pyproject uv-agnostic:
[project]
name = "my-project"
dynamic = ["version"]
requires-python = ">=3.10"
dependencies = ["django"]

[dependency-groups]
dev = ["factory-boy"]

Python Pinned
Also can make use of .python-version to pin the project Python version, which be created manually or by uv python:
uv python pin 3.10

Check version written to file
$ cat .python-version 
3.10

Dev venv
With the above configuration in place, a developer virtualenv can be created with:
uv sync

Finally activate venv:
source .venv/bin/activate


Here is link to original discussion
Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout
Adding this worked for me - I truly have no idea why though
[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []

Doing this I was able to run uv lock, and then uv sync and have everything install correctly from lock file

Thanks. I did since try something like that but it also created a my_project.egg-info/ directory and it all felt a bit more like it wanted me to build a distributable python package, rather than install dependencies for an existing Django-based website.
